# windows controls are disappearing in a win form after installing for adifferent locale

Tags: c#, localization

I am new to windows forms and localization.I have a windows  form which is containing some radio buttons and checkboxes and some buttons. this from is impleneted as a child form inside a master form. the problems i am facing now is when i install the english build controls are appearing as they are positioned while desinging. But the problem is when i install the danish build for the same app the controls are not visible in the UI. but they are available somewhere on the Winform. the reason for making this statement is when the tab+ enter keys are pressed the browse dailog which is availble in the UI is opening but could not see it.

I tried the following ways.
set the Locked property of the controls to true. 
set the autosize as true 
anchor all the controls to left..

please let me know if anyone have any pointers on this ..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what type of localization you guys do, so I might be not 100% right here, but it seems that Danish resx file (something.da.resx) defines incorrect Location for the missing controls. Make sure that Location and Size values are correct.

If you are using some kind of tool to localize the contents, still Location of the controls is likely the cause, but I can't tell you why it happen (version incompatibility?).